# MSSQL on Linux KDE neon 5.20 : Problem when installing the SQL Server command-line tools

Tags: kde, database

Assumed you have already intalled successfully mssql-server on your KDE neon instance.

At the step to install  mssql-tools and unixodbc-dev I have these errors :

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev
    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools : Depends: msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0) but it is not going 
 to be installed
           Depends: msodbcsql17 (< 17.4.0.0) but it is not going to be 
  installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by these steps.

**first, installed multiarch-support**:

1. get :
   `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`
2. install with dpkg:`sudo dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb`

**Second, installed dependencies**:

3. `sudo apt install libodbc1`
4. `sudo apt install unixodbc`
5. `sudo apt-get install msodbcsql17 -y`

**Finally, installed mssql-tools and unixodbc-dev**

6. `sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt install mssql-tools unixodbc-dev`

Now I can connect to server with `sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<MyPassword>'`